# Возможно ли задать "исключения" для запроса в jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток, гуглил - не нашёл информации:

1) Возможно ли сразу одним(!) запросом в jQuery выбрать скажем все <img>, кроме тех, у которых class, к примеру, `.noplay`

2) Возможно ли `$('.myplay_divs').each(function() { //mycode });` выполнять с задержкой скажем 500 для каждого элемента? и в общем, реально ли как то задержать(сделать паузу) определённого действия(анимации) jQuery не останавливая при этом другие?

Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$('img').not('.noplay')`
2. можно сделать:

`$('.myplay_divs').each(function (index, value) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            // your code 
        }, 500 * index);
    });`

Answer (score 4):

1)

```
$('img:not(.noplay)')
```

либо

```
$('input').not('.noplay')
```

2) курите про [setTimeout](http://javascript.ru/setTimeout)

Comment: Причём первый способ работает быстрее, особенно в современных браузерах.

Comment: ну это вытекает из логики построения этих селекторов - во втором сначала выбираются все img, а только потом к ним применяется фильтр not, а в первом фильтр может быть применен изначально. Хотя, в потроха jQuery я не лазил, точно сказать не могу, возможно, там применяется какая-то оптимизация

Comment: Просто т.к. селектор является валидным с точки зрения CSS, то браузеры ( конечно, если поддерживают ) могут применить querySelectorAll и выиграть в производительности. Если интересно, то вот тест производительности: http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not

Comment: @Genson, спасибо, любопытно